# Save updated Set in UserDefaults every time .insert() or .remove(at:) are called

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I’m sure this is a silly question, but I’m on a phone, and can’t find any similar questions.

I have a Set:

```
var mySet: Set<SomeObject>
```

That I need to persist across app launches, presumably using UserDefaults.

This works ok if I re-create and re-save the Set to UserDefaults every time it is modified, but that seems awfully cumbersome. Is there a way I can support updating the UserDefaults value every time `.insert()` or `.remove(at:)` are called?

Comment: What about adding a property observer (`didSet`) ?

Comment: Does didSet fire when insert is called? That would work.

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: Silly me! When my  battery is charged, I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a property observer for that purpose. Here is a simple
example for a set of integers (saved as an array):

```
var mySet = Set(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "mySet") as? [Int] ?? []) {
    didSet {
        // Save new value
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Array(mySet), forKey: "mySet")
    }
}
```

`Set` is a value type, and therefore each modification (insertion, 
removal, ...) stores a new value in the variable, and the property
observer is triggered.